# Angular /Spring REST API Post method problem

Tags: angular, spring

i have a problem with my post request sended from angular client to my backend RestAPI . To be clear when i send the same request from Postman it is working correctly! Other get request's or even post authorization Jwt request works correctly .
My restApiController post method :

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/cryptocurrency/{name}")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity addCryptocurrencyToUserFavouriteList(@PathVariable String name){
    logger.info("Calling /api/cryptocurrency/"+name+" POST method",CryptocurrencyController.class);
    try{
        String username=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        userService.addCryptocurrencyToFavourite(username,name);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Server Error "+ e, CryptocurrencyController.class);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.valueOf(404));
    }
}
```

angular Rest-api service:

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public addCryptocurrencytoUserFavouriteList(cryptocurrencyname: string):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL+"/cryptocurrency/"+cryptocurrencyname,this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Method is called from component just nothing happend ,neither on backend frontend side .I also have AuthIterceptor on angular side which is working correctly with other methods.
AuthInterceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';
  constructor(private token: TokenStorageService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let authReq = req;
    const token = this.token.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
      authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set(this.TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token)});
    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

So in my opinion problem could be in Post Method on server side , in the moment where im taking SecurityContext but before that instruction i had a logger info which didn't show in server output so idk what else i can do . Any ideas?
Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm not an Angular expert, but are you sure you send your request to the right address?

Comment: @k-wasilewski yeah im sure url are correct , authentication Token is added to header . And also other request for the same url are working so

Comment: But it's true that in some way backend controller isn't catching that request but i have no idea what's missing

Comment: And you're sure you do actually make that request? What does your browser networking console say?

Comment: i used console.logs to check if that method is actually called , and it is every time , but request by itself does not show up in the console

Comment: Then it's definately a frontend's issue, but I can't help you there...

Comment: @k-wasilewski i will try to dig deeper in angular ,thank you